# British Empire Budgets

Tags: data-request

Is there any open data on the public budget for the British empire across their colonies? Any other open data related to the administration of the colonies (such as heirarchy in each colony, allocation of expenditures, etc.) would also be interesting.

I'm specifically interested in the 1850-1950 time period.